# Pack Chrome extension on server with only command-line interface

Tags: google-chrome-extension, continuous-integration

Is it possible to pack chrome extension with key (*.pem) on server only with CLI (Ubuntu-server)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Update: chrome now uses Version 3 and the scripts released by google only worked for Version 2

There were official packaging scripts for Version 2 listed at [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx#scripts](http://web.archive.org/web/20180114090616/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx#scripts) - one in Bash and one in Ruby.
Google now wants apps to be packaged by them for the webstore.

However, here's a modified script that works for packaging CRX3 packages:

```sh
# Purpose: Pack a Chromium extension directory into crx format

if test $# -ne 2; then
  echo "Usage: crxmake.sh <extension dir> <pem path>"
  exit 1
fi

dir=$1
key=$2
name=$(basename "$dir")
crx="$name.crx"
pub="$name.pub"
sig="$name.sig"
zip="$name.zip"
tosign="$name.presig"
binary_crx_id="$name.crxid"
trap 'rm -f "$pub" "$sig" "$zip" "$tosign" "$binary_crx_id"' EXIT


# zip up the crx dir
cwd=$(pwd -P)
(cd "$dir" && zip -qr -9 -X "$cwd/$zip" .)


#extract crx id
openssl rsa -in "$key" -pubout -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -out "$binary_crx_id"
truncate -s 16 "$binary_crx_id"

#generate file to sign
(
  # echo "$crmagic_hex $version_hex $header_length $pub_len_hex $sig_len_hex"
  printf "CRX3 SignedData"
  echo "00 12 00 00 00 0A 10" | xxd -r -p
  cat "$binary_crx_id" "$zip"
) > "$tosign"

# signature
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign "$key" < "$tosign" > "$sig"

# public key
openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER < "$key" > "$pub" 2>/dev/null


crmagic_hex="43 72 32 34" # Cr24
version_hex="03 00 00 00" # 3
header_length="45 02 00 00"
header_chunk_1="12 AC 04 0A A6 02"
header_chunk_2="12 80 02"
header_chunk_3="82 F1 04 12 0A 10"
(
  echo "$crmagic_hex $version_hex $header_length $header_chunk_1" | xxd -r -p
  cat "$pub"
  echo "$header_chunk_2" | xxd -r -p
  cat "$sig"
  echo "$header_chunk_3" | xxd -r -p
  cat "$binary_crx_id" "$zip"
) > "$crx"
echo "Wrote $crx"
```

This script was revised based on information from the source code:

[Create Function](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/crx_file/crx_creator.cc?rcl=09de3b4e1e13cf10e431ba119b179169cde289fe)
[Header Description](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/crx_file/crx3.proto?l=1&rcl=09de3b4e1e13cf10e431ba119b179169cde289fe)

As well as the [serialization documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) for the header.

This script can easily be used in a docker container for automation:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache git openssl zip vim
COPY scripts/crxmake.sh /usr/local/bin/crxmake
```

Comment: Note that this answer assumes you are using an RSA key with a 2048-bit modulus. Here are replacement constants for 1024-bit and 4096-but moduli:

1024:
`header_length="41 01 00 00"`
`header_chunk_1="12 A8 02 0A A2 01"`
`header_chunk_2="12 80 01"`

4096:
`header_length="45 04 00 00"`
`header_chunk_1="12 AC 08 0A A6 04"`
`header_chunk_2="12 80 04"`

Comment: Here's a tip from an Old Dirty Bashtard: Any time you find yourself tempted to add a comment above a block of commands like `#extract crx id` or `#generate file to sign`, that really should be `function generate_file_to_sign(){ ... }` and you should call it in your `main` function (also missing). **We may not shave our necks, but we're not animals!**

Answer (score 27):

You can use the application switches `--pack-extension` and `--pack-extension-key` as described in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/linux_hosting/#package-through-command-line).

Basically, on Windows, you'd run the following in a terminal:

```
chrome.exe --pack-extension=c:\myext --pack-extension-key=c:\myext.pem
```

It works on Mac as well with:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --pack-extension=./myext --pack-extension-key=./myext.pem
```

It should be similar on Ubuntu.

Leaving out `--pack-extension-key` will automatically create a key for you.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't install Google Chrome on ubuntu-server. It has too many dependencies.

Comment: You may leverage a docker or VM @KhodeN

Comment: Anyone here in 2020: Installing chrome on Ubuntu is easy. You can use snapd

Comment: Including quotes in the arguments (`--pack-extension="./myext"`) causes the error "Input directory must exist." See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19398137/4842857