# Error packaging chrome extension at command line

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple ruby script to package and deploy a chrome extension. When running this code, I keep getting the error "Input directory must exist"

```
cmd = "#{chromePath} --pack-extension='#{sourcePath}' --pack-extension-key='#{keyPath}'"
puts "Command: " + cmd
puts `#{cmd}`
```

Outputs:

```
Command: C:\Users\Antoine\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --pack-extension='C:/Swaven/dev/B2C.Web.AdminPlugin/src' --pack-extension-key='C:/Swaven/dev/B2C.Web.AdminPlugin/b2c.Web.AdminPlugin.pem'
Input directory must exist.
```

But when I execute the command displayed, the `.crx` file is correctly generated!

Any idea why that is, and how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Chrome doesn't like it when you put quotes around your path names. I just ran into this issue, and removing the quotes (even if the path contained spaces) fixed it.