# Pack opera NEX extension via command line

Tags: opera-extension

Can you please assist on way to pack extension using command line and the developer key that we own?

I am afraid I haven't found anything in document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pack Chrome extension on server with only command-line interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693962/pack-chrome-extension-on-server-with-only-command-line-interface) (Chrome and Opera NEX extensions have the same binary format, so whatever works for Chromium also works for Opera)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Gist. It works fine for Chrome extensions and new opera extensions.
https://gist.github.com/paddyforan/820351

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/tut_basics.html#step_5__packing_it_all_up provides steps to pack an Opera extension. (in-browser though)

Comment: this solution can't be used in CI